# Changing duration time string in seconds

Tags: python, string, time

I'm currently automating a browsergame. In the game you can upgrade things and the time how long it takes to upgrade is given me in a string like so: 2d 4h 20m 19s
I want to compare different upgrade times, so I'd like to get the time into seconds so its easier to compare.

My Idea was to look what time is given, then get the index of that letter, look for the numbers in front of the letter, but i think thats a bit too much line of code, espacially if i have to do it more than one time.

My idea would have been sth like that:

```
if "d" in string:
    a = string.index("d")
if a == 2:
    b = string[a-2] * 10 + string[a-1]
    seconds = b * 86400
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the string up with `.split()` giving you a list: `['2d', '4h', '20m', '19s']`

Now we can do each part separately.

We can also use a conversion dictionary to give us what number to use depending on the suffix:

```
mod = {"d": 60*60*24, "h": 60*60, "m": 60, "s": 1}
```

Then we just sum the list, multiplying the number of each with the mod from above:

```
sum(int(value[:-1]) * mod[value[-1]] for value in ds.split())
```

This is equivalent to:

```
total = 0
for value in ds.split():
    number = int(value[:-1])  # strip off the units and convert the number to an int
    unit = value[-1]  # take the last character
    total += number * mod[unit]
```

where `ds` is the date string input.

Answer (score 0):

Below I've tried to split the process up into the basic steps:

```
In [1]: timestring = '2d 4h 20m 19s'                                                                     
Out[1]: '2d 4h 20m 19s'

In [2]: items = timestring.split()                                                                       
Out[2]: ['2d', '4h', '20m', '19s']

In [3]: splititems = [(int(i[:-1]), i[-1]) for i in items]                                               
Out[3]: [(2, 'd'), (4, 'h'), (20, 'm'), (19, 's')]

In [4]: factors = {'h': 3600, 'm': 60, 's': 1, 'd': 24*3600}                                             
Out[4]: {'h': 3600, 'm': 60, 's': 1, 'd': 86400}

In [5]: sum(a*factors[b] for a, b in splititems)                                                         
Out[5]: 188419
```

Like every code, this has some basic assumptions:

- Different units are separated by whitespace.
- The unit is only one code-point (character).
- Allowed units are days, hours, minutes and seconds.
- Numbers are integers.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I thinks thats the same thing the other guy posted and that works pretty well. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a helpful [`total_seconds()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) method on timedeltas.

**Given**

```
import datetime as dt


names = ["weeks", "days", "minutes", "hours", "seconds"]
s = "2d 4h 20m 19s"
```

**Code**

Make a dict of remapped name-value pairs and pass to `timedelta`:

```
remap = {n[0]: n for n in names}
name_time = {remap[x[-1]]: int(x[:-1]) for x in s.split()}
td = dt.timedelta(**name_time)
td.total_seconds()
# 188419.0
```